# Failed to load GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 using separate partitions with windows 8 already installed, grub didn't load so I used "Boot Repair" and did "Recommended Repair". Now while booting I get "FAILED TO LOAD UEFI 0000000XX.." AND "FAILED TO LOAD GRUB" then it directly loads to Ubuntu.
My boot repair generated link is http://paste.ubuntu.com/7685205/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) If you can boot to the rEFInd menu, you should see options for both Windows and Ubuntu. Try them both (or all; there may be redundant entries). If you can boot to both Windows and Ubuntu, install the rEFInd Debian package in Ubuntu. This *should* solve the problem, although there are enough buggy EFIs out there that there could be a follow-on problem.

Comment: Undo Boot-Repairs "buggy" UEFI fix first. Some UEFI only boot Windows, so Boot-Repairs fix has been to rename Windows to bkpbootmgfw.efi and rename shim to be bootmgfw.efi. Then system thinks it boots Windows but boots grub. But that creates other issues and best to be undone.   To undo & to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair.  Also 13.04 is not supported. Best to install 14.04.